# Cannot see Save as PDF option in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2010, save-as

When I want to save a document in PDF format I do not see the option in the option list of available formats offered by Ms Word 2010. I understand that this option is included with the product, you do not need to install any add-in.

¿Ther is some setting that I need to activate or anything I can check?

I appreciate you for your attention and help.

Best regards.

Alejandro.

Comment: this might help: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/save-as-pdf-in-office-2010-pdf-file-will-not/ab158b05-4711-4a18-b313-86c84504be77

Comment: *If you're using Windows 10*, you can use the Microsoft Print to PDF printer that's built-in in Windows 10, which can output to PDF from any application. This may not be what you're looking for, but posted it just in case you're looking for an alternative for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions of Office, the feature was available through a separate Add-In. Office 2010 has the save as pdf option built-in.

this feature is powered by this DLL

"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\EXP_PDF.DLL"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\EXP_PDF.DLL"
(the latter is for 32-bit DLL in a x64 Windows/Office)

Anyway, repair installation of Office should bring back the PDF option in the Save as dropdown.